# Prove: $E=\{x\in \Bbb R^n |\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p \leq1 \}$ is Jordan measurable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $p >0$ be some real number. I'm trying to prove that the set $E=\{x\in \Bbb R^n |\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p \leq1 \}$ is Jordan measurable.
I understand that $\partial E=\{x \in \Bbb R^n | \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p =1 \}$ (though I have not proved it formally yet). I want to show that $\partial E$ is a null set, but pretty stuck. Any ideas?

*Note* : I don't know much about measure theory, the only way I know to prove that a set is Jordan measurable is showing that the boundary is a null set.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: graph of a continuous function defined on a compact set has measure zero. Look at the set $F=\{x\in \Bbb R^{n-1} |\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|x_i|^p \leq1 \}$ and define a function $f:F\to \Bbb R$ by $f(x_1,...,x_{n-1})=\sqrt[p]{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|x_i|^p}$. Can you continue from here?